# Program execution freezes on datagramSocket.receive method if device in standby mode

Tags: android, udp, stun

I implemented STUN client which sends requests to STUN server with specified period and during this period listens for requests from STUN server:

```
try {

  byte[] respData = new byte[1024];
  DatagramPacket bRespPacket = new DatagramPacket(respData, respData.length);
  datagramSocket.setSoTimeout(timeout);
  datagramSocket.receive(bRespPacket); 
  processReceivedData(bRespPacket.getData());

  } catch (Exception e){}
```

If device goes into standby mode (when screen turns off) the program execution freezes on datagramSocket.receive() and no SocketTimeoutException is thrown until the screen becomes unlocked. When the screen unlocks, SocketTimeoutException is successfully thrown and program execution goes on.
What is the reason of such behavior?

**UPD:**
If device idle program execution freezes on datagramSocket.receive method and doesn't receive any incoming data. I tried using WifiLock but no results.

**UPD 2:**
If I use WakeLock all works fine, but I guess this isn't a good way

Answer (score 1):

To safe energy Android is shutting down components if the screen goes off. I guess this is somehow freezing your code execution. Maybe your socket gets disturbed when Android is shutting down WiFi.

As a quick workaround you could try to use a Wifi lock to prevent Android from that behavior. If that fixes your problem you should consider implementing it in a different way without a WiFi lock i.e. check the connection of the device and recreate your socket if it has changed.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.WifiLock.html

EDIT:

It tried it by myself and made a small example. The result was that I had no problems in receiving the UDP packages even with screen turned off and waiting a couple of minutes. I'm playing a sound on receiving and with screen turned off the playback got a bit jerky which proves that the phone was in standby mode.

I simply shot up a socket in a new thread straight from the activity an waited there for the socket.receive. Nothing special about it:

```
DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(port);

byte[] buf = new byte[256];

while(true) {
DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);

socket.receive(packet);

    // doing something with the data...
setOutputText(new String(buf));

}
```

I tested it on a Galaxy Nexus. Maybe you can provide more details about your problem?

Comment: If it is the case you must also listen to network state change , does not look like you are doing it.

Comment: thanks for response, but i still don't understand why execution freezes and goes on when screen unlocked

Comment: Edited the answer, please check.

Comment: Problem occured when device in discharging mode. If I use WakeLock or connect device to USB (charging mode) all works fine. I guess that Android slows down the processor in power saving mode and UDP receiving works but very very slow.

Comment: tested on Motorola MB526 DEFY and Samsung I5800 Galaxy